# Controlling access to instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have 2 users and 10 EC2 instances in my account. Now, I want the first user to view the instances related to him, but not the other instances. How can I restrict the user so that he could view only instances related to him ?

Comment: `related to him` is vague. Can be anyhing.

Comment: I didnt get you.Please explain

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by "I want the first user to view the instances related to him"? What do you mean by "view the instances"? Are you referring to seeing a list of instances displayed in the Amazon EC2 Management Console? And what do you mean by "related to" -- how do you consider an instance to be "related to" a particular User?

Comment: "view the instances" means to start,stop,delete instances. Related to in my sense meant ----- Ex: I have two users in my account. User A has created 5 instances only. User B has created 2 instances. Now, I want User A to view only the 5 instances he created and not the other 2 created by User B.